# Equivalence of Cauchy Sequences and Cauchy Approximations, HoTT

Tags: real-analysis, logic, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences, homotopy-type-theory

In HoTT book (Homotopy Type Theory), in order to construct Cauchy reals they introduce the notion of *Cauchy approximation*, which are defined as :

$$x \hspace{0.1cm} \colon \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R} \hspace{0.1cm} \mbox{such that} \hspace{0.1cm} \forall \hspace{0.1cm} (\epsilon, \delta \colon \mathbb{Q}_+). d(x_{\epsilon}-x_{\delta})< \epsilon + \delta$$

If I have a standard Cauchy sequence $x \hspace{0.1cm} \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ than I can obtain a Cauchy approximation via its modulus of convergence $M$, i.e. the function $\epsilon \to x_{M(\epsilon)}$.

On the other hand, if I have a Cauchy approximation I can get a Cauchy sequence for example by $n \to x_{\frac{1}{n}}$.

My question is : how do I show (if it's possible) that these two notions are equivalent if I'm interested only in their limits? More precisely :

- if I have a Cauchy approximation $x$ and two Cauchy sequences $\bar{x}, \tilde{x}$ obtained from $x$, is it true that $\mbox{lim}(\bar{x})= \mbox{lim}( \tilde{x})$ ?
- if I have a Cauchy sequence $x$ and two Cauchy approximations $\bar{x}, \tilde{x}$ obtained from $x$, do they have the same limit?

I think it would be sufficient to show that in either cases they are arbitrarily close.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is "HoTT"?

Comment: Homotopy Type Theory! Sorey, I'll explain it in the body for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what you mean by "obtained from", so let me make that definite:

- If $x$ is a Cauchy approximation, and $\epsilon_n,\delta_n : \Bbb N \to \Bbb Q_+$ are two sequences such that $\epsilon_n \to 0, \delta_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x(\epsilon_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} x(\delta_n) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} x(\epsilon)$$
- If $y$ is a Cauchy sequence, and $n, m : \Bbb Q_+ \to \Bbb N$ are two functions such that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}n(\epsilon) = \infty$ and $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}m(\epsilon) = \infty$, then
  $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}y_{n(\epsilon)} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}y_{m(\epsilon)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}y_n$$

(I am assuming $0\notin \Bbb Q_+$. If you are allowing $0 \in \Bbb Q_+$ then certain adjustments must be made in this post.)

Both of these follow from the fact that Cauchy sequences and approximations in $\Bbb R$ always converge, and a more general result about limits:

> If $X, Y, Z$ are topological spaces with maps (not necessarily
> continuous) $g: X \to Y, f: Y \to Z$ and $x_0 \in X, y_0 \in Y, z_0 \in Z$ such that
>
> 1. $g(x) \ne y_0$ in some deleted neighborhood of $x_0$,
> 2. $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x) = y_0$,
> 3. $\lim_{y \to y_0} f(y) = z_0$, then  $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(g(x)) = z_0$$

This is not hard to prove: if $W$ is a neighborhood of $z_0$, then because $\lim_{y \to y_0} f(y) = z_0$, there is a deleted neighborhood $V$ of $y_0$ with $f(V) \subset W$, and because $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x) = y_0$ there is a deleted neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ with $g(U) \subset V\cup{y_0}$, and by the first condition another deleted neighborhood $T$ of $x_0$ with $g(x) \ne y_0$ for all $x \in T$. Therefore $U\cap T$ is a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$ with $f\circ g(U\cap T) \subset W$. Since $W$ was arbitrary, $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(g(x)) = z_0$$